# Conversion - pyBind11 - Passing a torch.Tensor() in Python into a C++ method expecting a std::vector

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, tensor, pybind11

For a project I am working on, I require passing a PyTorch tensor (with dtype `torch.int16`) to a C++ method which expects an `std::vector` (basically, a list of integers).

I have the binding figured out, and I am already able to accomplish this task if I first convert my tensor into a numpy array (and use pybind11's numpy support), but for optimizing my code I want to be able to do this without this conversion to a numpy array.

Based on my research, I assume that I will have to write a custom type-caster. How should I proceed?

Comment: Can you add a MWE with instructions to compile? I have done this with glm vectors. Porting it to pytorch vectors should be rather straightforward

Comment: Is there a way to add a reference to the torch C++ api (torch/include/torch/csrc) and then use the Python tensor as at::Tensor in the C++ code (and then easily get the std::vector from the at::Tensor data) ?